# Manually add item to existing object [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, arrays, collections, eloquent, laravel-5

Here is what I try to do:

```
$q = Question::where('id',$id -> id)->get();
$q[] = $q->push([ 'test' => true]); 
dd($q);
```

This will output:

```
Collection {#220 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Question {#225 ▶}
    1 => array:1 [▼
      "test" => true
    ]
    2 => null
  ]
}
```

So `'test' => true` will append as a new key, but I want to insert it in `Question` so latter I can access to it like this with foreach `$q -> test`

So here is how I want access to item:

```
@foreach($q as $qq)
{{ $qq->test }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't understan 1 thing: Question::where('id',$id -> id)->get();   why You do not get element by primary key just using: Question::find($id);   ?

Comment: So funny to get collection of rows when it's always unique (:

Comment: If I use `find` is possible then to add new random attribut? to existing object

Comment: of course but, You'll lose ORM functions of it.

Comment: Ok,how can I do that?

Comment: read answer, updated it

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It can be done by using **setAttribute()** function of Eloquent Model (https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php).
As You can see it stores data in **protected $attributes** using **setAttribute()**, and when we do **$SomeModel->some_field**  it uses  magic method **__get()** to retrieve item by association from **attributes** array. 
Here is the resolution to Your question:

```
$Question = Question::find($id);
$Question->setAttribute('test', 'blablabla');
```

Comment: It will just create new object, it will not add attribute to my existing object... I taking attrinuts from database: `$q = Question::where('id',$id -> id)->get();` and I need on that attributes to add new one.

Comment: I am not sure it syntax ok? I get: `Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference`

Comment: It's now better but don't add new item inside attributes it adding on the end of object. any way to fix it?

Comment: here is picture: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/1o/ci/3p3OfzA3/screenshot-07172015-0345.png

Comment: Try secondary way, by using setAttribute method of Eloquent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83555/discussion-between-num8er-and-vladimir-djukic).

Comment: @Vladimir Djukic @num8er  In subsequent loops, how would I push to the array that was set up in the initial loop with `setAttribute()`?
I don't want to overwrite was was already set.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from `setAttribute()`, you can use `put()` refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44534142/6521116) for one item. And `map()` for many items, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534178/6521116).