# How to add new field in result query Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

So I have  model request:

```
$genres = Genre::all();
```

It gives me reuslt object:

```
"id" => 32
"name" => "Rock"
"position" => null
"updated_at" => "2017-02-07 06:16:46"
"created_at" => "2017-02-07 06:16:46"
```

How can I add new element `list = []` in this object?

Comment: `$genres->list = [];`

Comment: I have found solutions here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-add-a-new-element-to-every-item-of-collection?page=1

Comment: Try to use this solution: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474452/manually-add-item-to-existing-object-laravel-5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474452/manually-add-item-to-existing-object-laravel-5)

Comment: Maybe next time search for solution yourself before posting a question?

Comment: [map() on the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44534178/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

You can use map(), refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44534142/6521116).

```
->map(function ($item) {
  $item['test'] = ['123', '345'];
  return $item;
});
```