# Laravel how to add new field in query result

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, backend

How can I add new field in each item, I have used `put()` but it only add on the last item.

```
return self::where('latest', 1)
            ->where('competitionId',$competitionId)
            ->orderBy('won','desc')
            ->orderBy('teamName','asc')
            ->get(['teamName','played','won','lost','percentage', 'streak'])
            ->put('test', ['123', '345'])
            ->toJson();
```

Result:

```
{
"0": {"teamName": "A"},
"1": {"teamName": "B"},
"2": {"teamName": "C", "test": ['123', '345']},
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
"0": {"teamName": "A", "test": "qwerty"},
"1": {"teamName": "B", "test": "qwerty"},
"2": {"teamName": "C", "test": "qwerty"},
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use [map()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map)

```
->map(function ($item) {
  $item['test'] = ['123', '345'];
  return $item;
});
```

Comment: Collection {#389 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => null
    1 => null
    2 => null
    3 => null
    4 => null
    5 => null
    6 => null
    7 => null
  ]
}

Comment: it turns all item returns null

Comment: I foget the `return $item`;